# JavaFX: Set Scene min size excluding decorations

Tags: java, javafx, window

I know that with JavaFX you can set the Stage min size using `stage.setMinWidth()` and `stage.setMinHeight()`, however, this will include the window border (with the minimize, maximize, and close buttons).

How can I exclude this when setting the minimum size?

Answer (score 4):

You can show the `Stage` undecorated, which will remove all the borders:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

**If you want to have it decorated**

If you want to have it decorated you can set the size of the `Scene` to the preferred minimum size, then show the window (the `Stage` will have the size to be able to display the `Scene` with that size which one actually is your needed minimum size), then set the minimal size to the current size.

**Example:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private final int PREF_MIN_WIDTH = 500;
    private final int PREF_MIN_HEIGHT = 500;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(), PREF_MIN_WIDTH, PREF_MIN_HEIGHT);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, showing) -> {
                if(showing) {
                    primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
                    primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
                    primaryStage.setTitle("My mininal size is: W"+ primaryStage.getMinWidth()+" H"+primaryStage.getMinHeight());
                }
            });

            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This will produce a window like this:

[image]

Comment: It might be worth keeping in mind that if you set the minimum width and height of the stage before showing it, they get completely ignored: the user can resize the window to a size smaller than minimum widht and height you specified. So it has to be done with a listener, like @DVarga suggested

Answer (score 0):

Inside `void start(Stage primaryStage)`, put the following:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```