# JavaFX MediaPlayer - size of the Stage

Tags: java, javafx, size, stage, multimedia

I´m writing my own Multimedia application using MultiMedia classes from JavaFX 8. When I run(at the beginning) my program, I want to have the width and heigth of my `Stage` same as the width and heigth of media(video) I want to play.

```
mp.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Timeline slideIn = new Timeline();
            Timeline slideOut = new Timeline();

            stage.getScene().setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                slideIn.play();
            });

            stage.getScene().setOnMouseExited(e -> {
                slideOut.play();
            });
            // here I get the width and heigth of the media
            int w = mp.getMedia().getWidth();
            int h = mp.getMedia().getHeight();
            // width is 1280 and heigth is 720 (both values are correct)
            if (w != 0 && h != 0) {
                //Here Im setting the width and the height of stage
                //But when I run my app, stage is a little bit smaller than
                //MediaView and I have to resize the stage manually by cca 20px to get the whole view
                stage.setWidth(w);
                stage.setHeight(h);
                stage.centerOnScreen();

                //On the other hand, animation works pretty well and
                //correctly with the "w" and "h"
                mediaBar.setMinSize(w - 100, 100);
                mediaBar.setTranslateY(h - 100);
                mediaBar.setTranslateX(50);
                mediaBar.setOpacity(0);

                slideIn.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(new Duration(0), new KeyValue(mediaBar.translateYProperty(), h), new KeyValue(mediaBar.opacityProperty(), 0.0)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(300), new KeyValue(mediaBar.translateYProperty(), h - 100), new KeyValue(mediaBar.opacityProperty(), 0.9))
                );

                slideOut.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(new Duration(0), new KeyValue(mediaBar.translateYProperty(), h - 100), new KeyValue(mediaBar.opacityProperty(), 0.9)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(300), new KeyValue(mediaBar.translateYProperty(), h), new KeyValue(mediaBar.opacityProperty(), 0.0))
                );

                background.setWidth(w - 100);
                background.setHeight(100);
                background.setTranslateY(h - 100);
                background.setTranslateX(50);
                background.setOpacity(0);

                slideIn.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(new Duration(0), new KeyValue(background.translateYProperty(), h), new KeyValue(background.opacityProperty(), 0.0)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(300), new KeyValue(background.translateYProperty(), h - 100), new KeyValue(background.opacityProperty(), 1))
                );

                slideOut.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(new Duration(0), new KeyValue(background.translateYProperty(), h - 100), new KeyValue(background.opacityProperty(), 1)),
                        new KeyFrame(new Duration(300), new KeyValue(background.translateYProperty(), h), new KeyValue(background.opacityProperty(), 0.0))
                );
            } else {
                //music
            }
            duration = mp.getMedia().getDuration();
            updateValues();
        }
    });
```

So I guess, that there is something important about `Stage` class which I do not know yet.

When I set `initStyle` of `Stage` to `StageStyle.UNDECORATED`, then I can see the whole `MediaView`. But I do not want to have this style.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem ? I hope I described my problem correctly, because this is my first Ask for Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the stage height and width includes the decoration. From the [javadoc of widthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#widthProperty):

> This value includes any and all decorations which may be added by the
>   Operating System such as resizable frame handles. Typical applications
>   will set the Scene width instead.

And as you can see the solution is also in the documentation: you could set the size of the `Scene` instead.

This example opens a `Stage` which embeds a `Scene` with the size of 400x400.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Stage with 400x400 Scene");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.setOnShown(event -> System.out.println("Size of the Stage is " + primaryStage.getHeight() + "x" + primaryStage.getWidth()));

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Output is*

```
Size of the Stage is 438.0x416.0
```

So as you can see, if you set the size of the `Scene` the `Stage` will displayed to be bigger because of the decorations.

Update: Just found I had a really similar answer here: [JavaFX: Set Scene min size excluding decorations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603939/javafx-set-scene-min-size-excluding-decorations/37607519#37607519)