# JavaFX set stage minimum size to scene prefer size

Tags: user-interface, layout, javafx, fxml

I want to achieve like the app must be minimum size of 900x600 while the use can drag to resize to larger size. This is my primary scene:

```
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            minHeight="600.0" minWidth="900.0"
            prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0"
            styleClass="root" fx:controller="taidictionary.MainForm">
<!-- many controls -->
</BorderPane>
```

Below is the main app startup:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainForm.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setTitle("Tai Dictionary");        
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/TaiDictionaryIcon.png")));
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setMinWidth(900.0);
stage.setMinHeight(600.0);
stage.show();
```

The anomaly is that, I can still resize the window(stage) to smaller size than 900x600. Is this because of the paddings of the layout controls.

Comment: "The anomaly is that, I can still resize the window(stage) to smaller size than 900x600. Is this because of the paddings of the layout controls.". Sorry, could you explain the problem a bit in details?

Comment: Logically, I must only be able to resize the app to larger size than 900 x 600. But, I am being able to resize the app to slightly smaller size than 900 x 600. If I apply `stage.setMinWidth(920); stage.setMinHeight(620)`, then it becomes okay.

Comment: Ah, okay. The problem is the decoration of the Stage, as it is also counted when you set the min size. This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603939/javafx-set-scene-min-size-excluding-decorations